# Google Chart Visualization different number of bars

Tags: google-visualization, diagram

Hi I am trying to make a bar chart using the google bar chart visualization https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

I want to ask if I can use different number of bars for each field..

Let's say I have Asia, Europe, Africa and I have one bar for population in each of them. I want to add another bar ONLY in Europe for the average death rate.

As far as tried I couldn't find a way to do it, as you define the number of the bar and the titles from the beginning which include all the fields (Asia,Europe,Africa) so you can't add an addition bar for only one field.. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why not initialized the fields you don't want to 0 ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought about it but the problem is that I do not know before hand the number of the bars. It is a php site and every time the number changes. what I do is to take a string with the name (Asia) and then the collumn names with the values. I can't know before hand that Europe will have larger number of collumns. And there is where I want to create more..

Comment: So you should initialize them by default to 0 then add the value if one exist. At the moment you switch you will have to init the datatables of googlechart. I don't know but you could also have a look to dojo chart.

Comment: I thin that the alignment will not look that good... some bars will be close and some other will be far.. but thanks